# соединение через Socket

Tags: java

При соединение c каким любо сервером через Soket мне в консоль пишет:

> java.net.SocketInputStream@70dea4e

Что делать ? вот код:

```
package SFB;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class aaa {
    static private Socket connection;
    static private ObjectOutputStream output;
    static private String input;
    public static void main1(String[] args){

    }
        public static void main(String[] args){ {
            new Thread(new ser()).start();
            try {

                    connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1"), 80);
                    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());//отправляет 
                    InputStream in = connection . getInputStream ();//принимает
                    //System.out.print(in+"   ");   
                 System.out.printf(in+"   ");   
                    try {
                    } catch (HeadlessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    //private static void sendData(Object obj){
        try {
            output.flush();
            //output.writeObject(obj);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: System.out.printf(in+"   ");   
Вы же в консоль выводите объект а не данные, поэтому toString() в нем и выводит java.net.SocketInputStream@70dea4e

Comment: Можно данные с InputStream считать побайтово и через массив байтов вывести приведя к char !!! Или переопределить метод  toString() в класе InputStream.

Comment: можете показать как это будет выглядеть в коде, просто я не когда не сталкивался с  toString()

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решении не самое хорошее, но попробуй так !!!

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class aaa {
    static private Socket connection;
    static private ObjectOutputStream output;
    static private String input;
    public static void main1(String[] args){

    }
        public static void main(String[] args){ {
            new Thread(new ser()).start();
            try {

                    connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1"), 80);
                    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());//отправляет 
                    InputStream in = connection . getInputStream ();//принимает
                    //System.out.print(in+"   ");   

                 //!!!!!!!
                            int i=-1;
                            while((i=in.read())!=-1){
                                System.out.print((char)i);
                            } 
                //!!!!!!

                    try {
                    } catch (HeadlessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    //private static void sendData(Object obj){
        try {
            output.flush();
            //output.writeObject(obj);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Прочитайте как правильно читать с потока [здесь](http://metanit.com/java/tutorial/6.3.php)